# Monte Carlo sampling high dimensions with the halton sequence?

Tags: na.numerical-analysis, simulation, random-matrices, pr.probability

Referring to the Halton Sequence, [Swiler et al 2006](https://cfwebprod.sandia.gov/cfdocs/CCIM/docs/AIAASDMpaper49843.pdf) state that

> In cases where a large number  of input variables are sampled,
>   Robinson and Atcitty  recommend using a leaped sequence, where the
>   user does not  use every term in the Halton sequence but sets a “leap
>   value” to the next prime number larger than the largest prime  base. 
>   Using the leaped values in the sequence can help maintain uniformity
>   when generating sample sets for high  dimensions.

I can not track down the Robinson and Atcitty (1999) reference. But I am curious what the limitations are of using the Halton sequence to generate a quasi-random sample from an $n$-dimensional parameter space.

I am trying to minimize the number of samples required to estimate a response surface. To do this, I have been taking ~500 to 1000 samples from a set of 15-20 parameters.

How can I tell if I am having issues with uniformity with my sample - is there a simple visualization or other analysis? Are there alternative algorithms that do not have this problem? What options do I have other than reducing the dimension of parameter space or increasing the number of samples?

Also, (what is and) how do I implement a "leaped sequence". If I have an $n\times m$ matrix of samples from a Halton sequence, can I just delete specific rows?

Here is an example in R:

```
library(randtoolbox)
samps <- halton(n = 500, dim = 15)

head(signif(samps,3))
      [,1]  [,2] [,3]  [,4]   [,5]   [,6]   [,7]   [,8]   [,9]  [,10]  [,11]
[1,] 0.500 0.333 0.20 0.143 0.0909 0.0769 0.0588 0.0526 0.0435 0.0345 0.0323
[2,] 0.250 0.667 0.40 0.286 0.1820 0.1540 0.1180 0.1050 0.0870 0.0690 0.0645
[3,] 0.750 0.111 0.60 0.429 0.2730 0.2310 0.1760 0.1580 0.1300 0.1030 0.0968
[4,] 0.125 0.444 0.80 0.571 0.3640 0.3080 0.2350 0.2110 0.1740 0.1380 0.1290
[5,] 0.625 0.778 0.04 0.714 0.4550 0.3850 0.2940 0.2630 0.2170 0.1720 0.1610
[6,] 0.375 0.222 0.24 0.857 0.5450 0.4620 0.3530 0.3160 0.2610 0.2070 0.1940
      [,12]  [,13]  [,14]  [,15]
[1,] 0.0270 0.0244 0.0233 0.0213
[2,] 0.0541 0.0488 0.0465 0.0426
[3,] 0.0811 0.0732 0.0698 0.0638
[4,] 0.1080 0.0976 0.0930 0.0851
[5,] 0.1350 0.1220 0.1160 0.1060
[6,] 0.1620 0.1460 0.1400 0.1280
```

---

Swiler, L. P., Slepoy R., and Giunta, A. A., “Evaluation of Sampling Methods in Constructing Response Surface 
Approximations,” paper AIAA-2006-1827  in Proceedings of the  47th AIAA/ASME/ASCE/AHS/ASC Structures, 
Structural Dynamics, and Materials  Conference (2nd AIAA Multidisciplinary Design Optimization Specialist 
Conference), Newport, Rhode Island, 2006 [(pdf)](https://cfwebprod.sandia.gov/cfdocs/CCIM/docs/AIAASDMpaper49843.pdf)

Robinson, D.G. and C. Atcitty, 1999. "Comparison of Quasi- and Pseudo-Monte Carlo Sampling for Reliability and 
Uncertainty Analysis." Proceedings of the AIAA Probabilistic Methods Conference, St. Louis MO, AIAA99-1589.

Comment: It seems like some of your questions (especially with regard to a leaped Halton sequence) might be answered in Kocis and Whiten, Computational investigations of low-discrepancy sequences, ACM Transactions on Mathematical Software 23 (1997) pp. 266-294.

Comment: There is a lot of work out there extending the Sobol sequence to high dimensions, which may of relevance.